# native heap size increasing whenever application is launched

Tags: android

Native heap size of my application keeps increasing and finally crashes.

I have a couple of list views in my application and it is being populated from the database.
In the lisview, there are images and I have soft references to the bitmap image that is being loaded into the listview.

I also have option to view my application in different languages - English and Hindi.Whenever the user changes the language, I reload my application and this is increasing native heap size even though I have set FLAG_CLEAR_TOP and the activities are destroyed.I also set the locale when the language is changed.

I have also made sure all the lists are cleared when activities are destroyed.

Comment: Check this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to double check the ways you control your connections and data that you retrieve and keep in your application.

You have a Memory Leak in your application and it's kinda hard to catch it.The best you can do is that cleaning all your background cache and closing the connections whenever you do a major operation which will affect or restart the application.